# VerificationController #warning Handle the error here

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I have been working on integrating Apple's example [code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html) for In-App Purchase Receipt Validation on iOS into my app's codebase.

Does anyone know what to do with the two places in VerificationController.m that having the warning lines:

```
#warning Handle the error here.
```

as far as I can see the code is parsing some plist data or json data and turning it into a NSDictionary which then gets used to verify that the transaction info matches the receipt.

I don't know what needs to be done to properly handle the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no ill effects to ignoring these errors, the code seems to handle it just fine.

You will need to make sure that your implementation of:

```
- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input length:(NSInteger *)length
```

can handle receiving a nil NSString though!

Answer (score 0):

If the error occurred there, then the function

```
 - (BOOL)isTransactionAndItsReceiptValid:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
 {
   ......
   BOOL result = checkReceiptSecurity(transactionPurchaseInfo, signature,
                                   (__bridge CFDateRef)(purchaseDate));
   if (!result)
   {
       return NO;
   }
```

will `return NO` expectedly. So, I simply replace the `#warning ...` with:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

just for debug purpose.